# Pytho, BeautifulSoup - web scraping 'find_all' is returning NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the website the below image was what I am getting.
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/'

I have tried all similar solution on stackoverflow but it is not working for me

```py
table_data=soup.find('table', {"id" : "example2"}, class_='table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer')

headers = []
for i in table_data.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text
    headers.append(title)
```

```
Error message
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-e8b5de995a9d> in <module>
      1 table_data=soup.find('table', {"id" : "example2"}, class_='table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer')
      2 headers = []
----> 3 for i in total_data.find_all('th'):
      4     title = i.text
      5     headers.append(title)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

this is the code I tried to use in scraping the table but it is not working too. Further help

```
for j in table_data.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        row_data = j.find_all('td')
        row = [tr.text for tr in row_data]
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = row


ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined columns
```

Comment: What is `total_data`? Did u mean `table_data`?

Answer (score 0):

"findAll" is a Beautiful soup function, meaning you would have to use:

```
soup.findAll('th')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the page and i've used:

```py
table_data = soup.find('table', id="example2")
columns = [x.text for x in table_data.find("thead").find_all("th")][1:]
rows = [[x.text for x in y.find_all("td")][1:] for y in table_data.find("tbody").find_all("tr")]
dt = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```

test it ;-)

Comment: @dhrey112 Oh! let me delete my answer then. Find the table.